# Trouble loading csv file in SAS

Tags: csv, sas

I am trying to load a `.csv` file into `SAS` using the program:

```
proc import datafile= "&path/newemps.csv" out =orion.newsalesemps1 dbms=csv replace;
getnames=yes;
run;
proc print data = orion.newsalesemps1;
run;
```

The program runs with no errors but the column names being used are taken from the second row of the original data file rather than the first row. Can anyone help me understand what is exactly going wrong here?

The first row of the original data file has texts in formats that can be read by `SAS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the `namerow=` and `startrow=` options explicity :

```
proc import datafile= "&path/newemps.csv" out =orion.newsalesemps1 dbms=csv replace;
getnames=yes;
namerow=1;
startrow=2;
run;
proc print data = orion.newsalesemps1;
run;
```